# I have downloaded gparted and tried to start with (Alt+F2) but I get a window that informs I must have root-priviliges

Tags: partitioning, 17.10, gparted, wayland

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> work, but it doesn't give me access to `gparted`. 
I have never worked with a program in the terminal before, just written code/commands. 
Do I have to use `sudo` to open up `gparted`? And what else?
Graeme

Comment: Instead of "gparted", just run "sudo gparted".

Comment: @davidbaumann [Not a good idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications), run `gksu gparted` instead.

Comment: @pomsky `gksu` is dying too. It's no longer supported when using Wayland instead of Xorg, and it isn't installed by default any more for a while already.

Answer (score 3):

GParted needs root privileges to run. It comes with a wrapper that asks you for your admin password and elevates its privileges, called `gparted-pkexec`. You have to run that one instead of `gparted` directly.

However, you say you downloaded GParted. If you mean by this that you downloaded it off some website, you normally shouldn't have done that. GParted is available from the official Ubuntu repositories and can be installed using

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

or through your Software Center. This version will make sure GParted is well integrated into your system and e.g. provide a launcher icon, so you don't have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: I have tried all suggested commands, I still have no access to gparted. Is it supposed to open through the terminal? PS I downloaded from Software Centre

Comment: No, GParted is a graphical application, you don't need to start it from the terminal, but you can. If you try and type `gparted-pkexec` in the terminal, what exactly happens then? Does it ask for the admin password? Does GParted start up and show any windows? Are there error messages in the terminal?

Comment: :~$ gparted-pkexec
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.

(gpartedbin:9433): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
There was a lot more but this site only allows a small no characters. Gparted has yet to show any signs of opening. In or out of the terminal. A separate window opened for the password.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the complete output. Also, what Ubuntu version and desktop environment are you using? Do you know whether you're on Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: :~$ gparted-pkexec
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/media-ubuntu-A107\x2d2558.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/media-ubuntu-Backup\x20copy.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/snap-core-4206.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/snap-core-4327.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/snap-core-4407.mount → /dev/null.

Comment: Created symlink /run/systemd/system/snap-spotify-13.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/snap-spotify-6.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:2781): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Removed /run/systemd/system/-.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/media-ubuntu-A107\x2d2558.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/media-ubuntu-Backup\x20copy.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount.
I have to send in three parts

Comment: Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/snap-core-4206.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/snap-core-4327.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/snap-core-4407.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/snap-spotify-13.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/snap-spotify-6.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 which I plan to change to Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I asked you to edit your question to add the output, exactly because of its length and because comments don't allow proper formatting. Important information should always be edited into the question.

Comment: I don't understand, you asked for the total output and that is what I tried to give you. I don't understand how I'm supposed to edit the terminals output into my reply to what you asked for.  But in any case right now all I want is to understand why I can not open gparted.

Comment: There is an edit button below your original question, which you can use to add additional information. However, the problem you have is most likely already solved anyway, so see the linked duplicate question for a solution.

Comment: Ok I got gparted to open, but I also got a error warning. Libparted warning:Error fsyncing/closing/dev/sdd:1/O-fel on fjärrmaskin Swedish for O.error/problem on externalmachine    Graeme

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for this follow-up issue.